# Is it possible to hire a car in Norway with a debit card?

Tags: automobiles, payment-cards, rental, norway

We have been told that it is impossible to hire a car in Europe without a credit card. We only have a debit card (with the Visa logo). Is there anyway around this? We are in Norway where you seriously need a car, and we want to go camping.

Comment: From my experience in most of Europe (well, at least for 3 specific nations which lie scattered from west till far eastern europe) debit cards tend to be the norm more than credit cards, so this seems quite a queer thing@impossible to hire cars without cc's.

Answer (score 6):

I am a Norwegian, living in Norway. I have hired cars (at Hertz) with both debit and credit cards (all Visa) without any problems.

Answer (score 4):

I would honestly be surprised if it's generally not possible to use debit cards as payment for rental cars in Norway.

At least Avis states clearly in their [terms and conditions](http://www.avis.no/omavisno/leiebetingelser/leiebetingelser-i-norge) that when using Visa debit cards, an additional 20% is reserved on top of the rental fee.